# named entity recognition using seq2seq model such as transformer?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

Can we use neural machine translation (like seq2seq) for named entity recognition?such as  USING TRANSFORMER nerual network FOR NER TASK. SOURCE IS WORD SEQUENCE, TARGET IS TAG sequence LIKE "o o o PERSON o o o location"，is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Transformer-based language models for NER tasks. You may check this paper [BERT: Pre-training of Deep Bidirectional Transformers for Language Understanding](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805). The pre-trained Transformer-based language models are utilized as transfer learning (i.e., fine-tuning) to further use for some tasks, such as Question Answering, Text Classification, Named Entity Recognition, etc.